# How to get MassTransit Mediator to publish notifications in background?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, background-process, masstransit, mediator

I'm trying to get **MassTransit Mediator** to **publish notifications** in a **background process** so that the system doesn't have to wait for all consumers to complete and it can return a response asap.

There is an API for creating Companies. When a Company is created, I have to run a couple of processes, such as adding the Company to a cache and downloading/storing a file.
The thing is that I don't want the client to wait for those two things to complete, I want them to run in the background.

I found on Google some implementations using HangFire to have Mediator publishing messages from a background job, but I think it's not worth it to add a dependency to HangFire just for this simple use case.

I would love to hear any options/ideas/recommendations for implementating this.

```
public interface CompanyCreated
{
    Guid CompanyId { get; }
}

public class UpdateCompanyCache : IConsumer<CompanyCreated>
{
    public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<CompanyCreated> context)
    {
        // [...]
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
    }
}
public class DownloadCompanyFile : IConsumer<CompanyCreated>
{
    public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<CompanyCreated> context)
    {
        // [...]
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2));
    }
}

public class CompanyService
{
    public async Task<Company> CreateAsync([...])
    {
        // [...]
        
        await _mediator.Publish<CompanyCreated>(new
        {
            CompanyId = company.CompanyId
        });
        
        return company;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Mediator is, by design, meant to dispatch messages in-process, in-memory, without serialization or background processing. The only difference between `Send` and `Publish` is whether or not the message *must* be handled by a consumer.

If you need reliable background processing, you should use a bus with a durable transport (such as RabbitMQ, Azure Service Bus, etc.) to ensure that published messages are properly handled. Those messages would be handled asynchronously, which meets your requirements.

If you don't care at all if the message is actually handled, just use `Task.Run()` to execute a background task. Be aware that background task may not actually complete if the process exits.

Comment: Chris, thanks for your comment. It makes much sense... btw, is it common for applications to consume messages published by itself?

Comment: I'd recommend [watching the mediator video first](https://youtu.be/dxHNAn69x6w) and then watching the [move to RabbitMQ](https://youtu.be/97PXJIrGnes) to understand how a broker-based messaging solution differs from an in-process mediator pattern implementation.